# What force provide tangential velocity change in whirling block problem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

In whirling block problem as given below, I understand that Tension force is acting as central force in its motion so its angular momentum is conserved.
[image]
With time r will decrease if system is left isolated, and since angular momentum is conserved as r decreases its tangential velocity will increase. I want to know what force provides this change in tangential velocity of object.

I searched about this and found whats below but could not understand the tangential equation.
[image]

Comment: If you want help with homework questions you should at least make an effort to type them out with [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so your question and working is more legible.

Comment: It is not an homework problem. I am in high school. I don’t know mathjax. It is my first question here. Sorry if I had wrongly framed. I am preparing for my entrance exams so I just had this doubt.

Comment: It's fine, just for future reference it helps to have as much of your question typed out as possible and avoid just posting pictures, especially if it's just a screenshot from your phone. If you want someone to take the time to read your question and answer it you're more likely to get a better response if they can read it without too much trouble.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can tangential acceleration from a radial force be explained?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185240/how-can-tangential-acceleration-from-a-radial-force-be-explained) See also [How does an object undergoing circular motion increase its tangential velocity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293882)

Comment: Thanks a lot, understood the doubt. Thank you.