# Why dose when a person increasing the tangential speed of a ball in a circle, their hand traces out and ellipse?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Why dose when a person increasing the tangential speed of a ball in a circle, their hand traces out and ellipse? A video of this can be seen at youtu.be/B0G_6awN6fA?t=47 when watched at 0.25 play back speed

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/712983/2451

Comment: In particular this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293882/how-does-an-object-undergoing-circular-motion-increase-its-tangential-velocity